# Get Remote Host IP in Web API Self-Hosted Using Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, ip-address, owin

I need a very simple thing - get remote host IP address in Web API controller. [This](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/retrieving-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api/) post describes how to do this when you are web hosting or self hosting. Unfortunately, the described solution does not work with [Web API self-hosted using Owin](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) (well, I couldn't make it work:)). I use windows service to host Web API.

So, the question is: **How to get remote host IP address in Web API controller which is self-hosted in windows service using Owin**?

Controller where I need remote IP address:

```
internal class ItemController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddItem([FromBody] string data)
    {
        // Need to get remote host IP address here

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Start up class that configures Web API:

```
internal class StartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        httpConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }
}
```

I use Windows service to host Web API. Below is the service's OnStart method:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:5550/";
        // Start OWIN
        WebApp.Start<StartUp>( url: baseAddress );            
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to get it by doing the following:

```
OwinContext owinContext = (OwinContext)webapiHttpRequestMessage.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];
string ipaddress = owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I was looking into OwinContext.Environment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in my Owin controller (System.Web.Http.Owin v5.2.7):

```
    var ctx = Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"] as OwinContext;
    if (ctx != null)
    {
        var ip = ctx.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
        var port = ctx.Request.RemotePort;
        LogInfo($"Remote caller = {ip}:{port}");
    }
```